# Filtering pandas data frame with tabulated function

Tags: python, filter, pandas

I am trying to filter a pandas data frame df containing `columns A` and `B` with a tabulated function: I want to retain all values where the `df.B` value exceeds a limit which is dependent on `df.A`, i.e. `df.B>limit[i]` where i is calculated from `df.A` like `i=floor(df.A)`.

Unfortunately, I am not that experienced in Python. But it is clear to me that the element-wise comparison is very inefficient, and I found the function `df.query` which seems helpful for this, but I was not successful.

```
Excerpt of the data frame df:

datetime             A     B          
2014-05-31 03:30:00  2201  18.2
2014-05-31 03:40:00  2208  18.7
2014-05-31 03:50:00  2205  20.6
2014-05-31 04:00:00  2202  19.9
2014-05-31 04:10:00    22  18.2
2014-05-31 04:20:00  2204  18.2
2014-05-31 04:30:00  2198  18.1
2014-05-31 04:40:00  2204  19.1
2014-05-31 04:50:00  2202  20.3
2014-05-31 05:00:00  2205  20.8
...

limit = [  0.0,    10.0,   40.0,   100.0,   240.0,   300.0,   480.0, 800.0,  1000.0, 1400.0,  1600.0,  1800.0,  
1900.0,  1900.0, 1900.0,  1900.0, 1900.0,  1900.0,  1900.0,  1900.0,  1900.0  ]
```

I tried the following:

```
In [54]: df.query ( "df['A'] > limit[floor(df['B'])]")
... 
NotImplementedError: 'Call' nodes are not implemented

In [55]: df.query ( "df['A'] > limit[floor(2.3)]")
...
NotImplementedError: 'Call' nodes are not implemented

In [56]: df.query ( "df['A'] > limit[12]" )
Out[56]:     
datetime             A     B          
2014-05-31 03:30:00  2201  18.2
2014-05-31 03:40:00  2208  18.7
2014-05-31 03:50:00  2205  20.6
...

(it works)
```

I use Python 2.7.6.2, Numpy 1.8.0 and Pandas 0.13.0

Can anyone explain me why I cannot use the `floor` function within this expression, respectively how to accomplish this filtering?

Thanks.

Comment: Ca you post data and code, python, pandas and numpy version so we can reproduce your error, thanks.

Comment: It's still not clear exactly what answer you are looking for.  What do you want `limit[floor(df['B'])]` to evaluate as?  Just type a few lines of desired output (being clear it is desired not actual).  I think with limit[] you are trying to create an index but I don't know what you are trying to accomplish with floor().

Comment: Specifically in regards to limit, I don't think it's behaving as you expect here but if you make it a numpy array then it might.

Comment: Probably this is not a very "pythonic" neither an elegant way, but the array `limit` defines only a lower limit for the value A, which is dependent on the value B. 
I have tabulated this limit as values for each integer, that is the meaning of the `floor`.

Comment: A further explantion otherwise it might not be clear:  I have tabulated the limit "function" as values for each integer of B, which is represented by the index, so limit[1] is the limit for all values from 1 to 1.99, limit [2] for 2 to 2.99, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to do something like this?

```
lim = np.array(limit)
df['C'] = lim[ df.B.astype(int).values ]

      A     B     C
0  2201  18.2  1900
1  2208  18.7  1900
2  2205  20.6  1900
```

I'm just using integer truncation instead of floor to save a step.  And I think regardless of what you are trying to do you need to use a numpy array rather than a python list.

Comment: Great, thank you very much. I just included your solution in the filter statement `df [  df['A'] > lim[ df.B.astype(int).values ] ]` (I want to avoid duplicationg the data as I have a big amount).

Comment: Yes, that is the traditional way here!  When you have a higher rep you can also upvote and give multiple answers credit if you want.

Comment: I have `NaN` values in `B` in my big data set, which create a problem when being interpreted as int. I am sure there is a very elegant and short way to solve this, which I did not find yet. MAybe someone might give me a hint.